# How to set expire date for PageSpeed Insights google in Laravel?

Tags: htaccess, page-speed

I create `.htaccess` in root project and add this code for set expire date for css and js.

My server is **Ubuntu 16.04**

But this code not work for my website.

This code in htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\\.(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2692000, public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\\.(x?html?|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
Header unset ETag
Header unset Last-Modified
</IfModule>
```

How do I fix the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Are mod_expires and/or mod_headers installed on your server? Remove the `<IfModule>` wrappers - do you get an error? "My server is Ubuntu 16.04" - since you've included your `.htaccess` file, I assume you are on Apache? Which version? Both your rule blocks are doing the same sort of thing - why are you using both mod_expires and mod_headers - is this code intended to work on different servers? "in Laravel" - since Laravel is a PHP framework, if you wanted to do this "in" Laravel implies you want to do this "in PHP" - but I assume that's not the case?

Comment: Hi @w3dk, Thank you for help me. I now run mod_expires in apache :-) Please create answer for like your answer :-)

Comment: Is it now working? (I didn't really have an answer, only questions?)

Comment: @w3dk , Yes now i see expire date in header :-) Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can add an answer yourself stating what you did to resolve the problem? (You can later accept it.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that `mod_expires` is actually enabled.  On Ubuntu, it comes shipped with Apache2, but it is not enabled by default.   To enable it, run the commands:

```
sudo a2enmod expires
sudo service apache2 restart
```

`a2enmod` is the apache2 script that enables a module.   If you want to disable the module, you would use `a2dismod` instead.

After the module has been enabled, Apache2 much be either restarted, or it needs to reload its config files.   The second command does the latter.